# ¿Cómo programar un cron trigger en quartz para que corra PM-AM?

Tags: java, quartz, crontrigger

Tengo un cron trigger en [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) v2.3.2 que se programa desde la interfaz de usuario, en un intervalo que va de tarde en la noche hasta la madrugada del día siguiente (digamos, cada día de 10PM hasta el día siguiente 4AM).

En la tabla qrtz_cron_triggers, el trigger queda guardado con la siguiente definición: `0 0/5 22-4 * * ?`

En la práctica, los usuarios están viendo que el proceso falla cuando la configuración tiene este valor y no hay ningún error en la aplicación asociado a esta ejecución. Simplemente no se ejecuta cada 5 minutos y no realiza la tarea asociada al trigger.

En la [documentación](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/examples/Example3.html) y en los ejemplos incluidos en la versión no hay detalles sobre ésto. Sólo encuentro [algunas cosas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67158/crontab-entry-with-hour-range-going-over-midnight) sobre los cronjobs común y corrientes, en los que los líos se resuelven usando dos triggers, uno por cada intervalo.

¿Alguien sabe si quartz permite expresiones "overnight" o toca usar dos triggers para cubrir un intervalo que va de un día al otro? Digamos, algo como

```
0 0/5 22-23 * * ?
0 0/5 0-4 * * ?
```

o tal vez algo como

```
0 0/5 22-23,0-4 * * ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He realizado algunas pruebas y con el `Scheduler de Spring` no me funciono la expresión `0 0/5 22-4 * * ?` pero si por intervalos `0 0/5 22-23,0-4 * * ?`, pero con la librería `quartz 2.3.2` el cron `0 0/5 22-4 * * ?` y `0 0/5 22-23,0-4 * * ?` funcionaron sin ningún problema lo que yo siempre hago en estos casos es crearme una clase para validar las ejecuciones segun la librería que utilices por ejemplo para `Quartz` cree esta clase que te puede ayudar en futuras referencias:

```
import org.quartz.CronExpression;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

public class QuartzValidation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String cronExpression = "0 0/5 22-4 * * ?";

        System.out.println("Is Valid:" + CronExpression.isValidExpression(cronExpression));
        CronExpression expression = new CronExpression(cronExpression);

        Date executionTime = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            executionTime = expression.getNextValidTimeAfter(executionTime);
            System.out.println(executionTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Libreria:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Muestra de Ejecución para demostrara la ejecución al cambio de hora:

```
Is Valid:true
Thu Feb 18 23:00:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:05:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:10:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:15:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:20:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:25:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:30:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:35:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:40:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:45:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:50:00 CET 2021
Thu Feb 18 23:55:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:00:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:05:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:10:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:15:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:20:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:25:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:30:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:35:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:40:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:45:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:50:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 00:55:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 01:00:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 01:05:00 CET 2021
Fri Feb 19 01:10:00 CET 2021
```